# rspec: What is the precise meaning of "example" for the caching of `let`?

Tags: rspec

The [relishapp docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-11/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let) mention that the value of `let` is cached across the same example:

> Use let to define a memoized helper method. The value will be cached
>   across multiple calls in the same example but not across examples.

It doesn't exactly say what an "example" is, but I'm taking that to mean the topmost `describe` or `context` block. Is that correct? If so, can you link to documentation stating that explicitly?

Elsewhere, the docs note the following:

> The describe method creates an example group. Within the block passed
>   to describe you can declare nested groups using the describe or
>   context methods, or you can declare examples using the it or specify
>   methods.

So is an "example" a `context/describe` block, or an `it` block? In short, what exactly is the scope of a `let` value: an `it`, or a `context/describe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By example it means a `leaf` in your specs tree

Check out this made up specs:

```
RSpec.describe MyClass do
  let(:x) { 1+2+3 }
  describe '#foo'
    context 'when x happens'
      specify do
        expect(subject.foo).to eq(x)
      end
    end
    specify do
      expect(subject.foo).not_to eq(x)
      expect(subject.foo).not_to eq(x+1)
    end
  end
end
```

`x` will be calculated once and only once for each `specify` block. If you use it inside more than once (like in the second `specify` in the example. The second usage will be just retrieving of memoized value (`1+2+3` will not be calculated again).

But for each `specify` the value will be calculated (unless it's not used, because `let` is also lazily evaluated)

You also ask about the scope of the `let` and this is something different: the scope (as in scope where this defined element is avaliable) is the block you define it in. And it bubbles down to each `it/specify` block which is inside it.

Answer (score 0):

An example is an it block, you can see this fairly easily by seeing that between it blocks the let value is not cached and repopulated.

The second paragraph you cite mentions describe as creating a "group" of examples.